# Gsap.js - элемент не появляется

Tags: javascript

Мне достался чужой код, в котором используется Gsap.js, и я не могу отловить ошибку, почему методы не срабатывают, и элемент остается с теми свойствами, которые были прописаны как начальные. Думала, что не срабатывает триггер, но судя по изменениям в коде в браузере элементы все же реагируют.

В HTML 4 блока, которые должны появляться, когда скролл ниже предыдущего блока.

```
gsap.from('.three__item', {
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: '.two',
    start: 'top top',
  },
  opacity: 0,
  stagger: .1,
  height: 0,
})
```